# Existence of a colum matrix such that norm of the colum matrix after operated on by a matrix is one?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For  any given matrix $A$ ( $m$ x $n$ ) is it possible to find a $n$ x $1$ column matrix such that 
                             $$|Av| >0, \; \text{where }\; |v|=1$$
Here $|\; |$ stands for norm. All the entries of matrices are complex. I intuitively find it true if in place of $ \; > 0 $ we  have $\;\ge 0$  ( might be wrong ) but can't prove it for either of the cases .

Comment: Not true, take $A=0$. $|Av|\ge0$ holds trivially by the properties of the norm,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A is not the $0$-matrix it is possible to find a vector $w$ which isn't mapped to $0$. Then $|Aw|>0$ which is by definition of a norm. Just divide $w$ by its norm and there's your $v$.